# Laravel barryvaddh - dompdf undefined property error

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

In my education resources controller system, we have to prepare progress reports for student.To get these reports as a pdf I used Laravel dom-pdf.

code of pdfGeneratorController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Subject;
use PDF;

class pdfGenerator extends Controller
{

public function reportPdf()
{
   $users = DB::table('users')->get();
   $subjects = DB::table('subjects')->get();
   $pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports', ['users' => $users],['subjects' => $subjects]); 
   // $pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports', ['subjects' => $subjects]); 



   return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
}

  public function report()
    {
       // $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('subjects','users.id','=','subjects.user_id')
        ->join('marks','subjects.user_id','=','subjects.user_id')
            ->select('users.*','subjects.subject','marks.marks')
             ->get();


        //$subject = Subject::all();
       // return $subject;
        return view('reports', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

codes of reports.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="{{url('/pdfs')}}" > Download pdf</a></h1>
<table>
<caption>Student Details</caption>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td> lname    </td>
<td>subject</td>
<td>marks</td>



</tr>
@foreach($users as $user)

<tr>

    <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->lname}}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->subject}}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->marks}}</td>






@endforeach

</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click reports link it shows all the relevant data webpage. but when i  click print pdf link it gives a error.the error  of this time is  ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$subjects (View: E:\nimnayawebsite\resources\views\reports.blade.php)

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: what's the error here??

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$subject (View: E:\nimnayawebsite\resources\views\reports.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying yo use `$user->subject` in the view. Since `report()` method works for you with the same view, change this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$subjects = DB::table('subjects')->get();
```

To:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('subjects','users.id','=','subjects.user_id')
    ->join('marks','subjects.user_id','=','subjects.user_id')
        ->select('users.*','subjects.subject','marks.marks')
         ->get();
```

Comment: that subject means the column name of the subject table.for identify subject name instead of name i used subject.

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga please put `{{ dd($users) }}` to the view and show full output.

Comment: this time it retrives all the data related to user table.but i think now my report pdf () function is not working. i can not get a output as a pdf.the data retrive as  Collection {#603 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#599 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"usertype": 0
      +"name": "Mihiran"
      +"lname": "Chathuranga"
      +"email": "mihiran.chathuranga@gmail.com"
      +"verifyToken": "6lEQNVIudRkDzf7vUYicYDt6KP4NM724drm6p3B4"
      +"status": null
      +"avatar": "default.jpg"
      +"dob": "2018-01-02"

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga I don't see `subject` column in the results you've shown. Did you try to change the query as I've shown?

Comment: sorry it not gives subject table data.because of the comment too long i removed part of it.but it not shows the data in sunjects table

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga as I've asked before, please show full output. Do not remove anything. Unfold all folded objects and post somewhere.

Comment: sorry how i can do it.comment field is not sufficent to post all the things

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VJfAbyz0oZ2leOAks3WOg_MRUR95_Lbx    here i add those things

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga I still don't see `subject` in the results. And these are not full.

Comment: subjects  is a table of my database.subject is a column of it.but after using {{dd users}} it shows users table data.it not shows subjects table data

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga you've said it's a column. Just try to use the code as I've shown in the answer.

Comment: i used the your suggestions Alexey Mezenin.thank you.now no error.but my reportpdf function is not working.my purpose is get result as a pdf.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uFGUfUFYPruxM6ULgH-zXa5Mkmd2_GWE please give me a solution

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga what do you mean by not working? There isn't downloading? If this is the problem, I can't help, sorry. Your code looks fine (the package docs show the same example). Maybe you should create another question for this.

Comment: thank you very much .yes i can not download it as a pdf now.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `two array` with `comma` separated value, pass it making `one array`.

Change this line-

```
$pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports', ['users' => $users],['subjects' => $subjects]);
```

To this-

```
$pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports', ['users' => $users,'subjects' => $subjects]);
```

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$subject (View: E:\nimnayawebsite\resources\views\reports.blade.php)****Undefined property: stdClass::$subject   it gives again this errors

Comment: show your full blade template code, where you have used subjects??

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga which line you are getting the error??

Comment: i put {{ dd($users) }} as below comment.now it retrives data in browser.but my reportpdf() function not working.i can not get output as a pdf

Comment: remove `,'subjects' => $subjects` and see what happen?? If you could tell exactly which line causing the problem, we can help you then

Comment: i used the your suggestions of  Alexey Mezenin..now no error.but my reportpdf function is not working.my purpose is get result as a pdf.drive.google.com/open?id=1uFGUfUFYPruxM6ULgH-zXa5Mkmd2_G‌​WE please give me a solution

Comment: yes i can not download output as a pdf.the error occur when i used <td>{{ $user->subject}}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->marks}}</td> parts in blade .php without them i can download pdf.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JSSbI85zN8VOePObA_1oTKWSZFqhkpfc

Comment: show `dd($users)` after adding new query and make sure to expand it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163783/discussion-between-mihiran-chathuranga-and-sohel0415).